# switching rsyslog destination file if a directory exists

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

I have configured rsyslog server to send logs from some remote hosts to specific files in my application directory like that:

```
$template TmplApplication, "/whatever/jboss/logs/%fromhost-ip%/sum.log"
if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then  {
-?TmplApplication
stop
}
```

So, for example logs from `1.2.3.4` will be sent to `/whatever/jboss/logs/1.2.3.4/sum.log`.

But now, i'm changing my application from jboss to wildfly so I'm changing the directory name from `/whatever/jboss/logs/` to `/whatever/wildfly/logs`.

I would prefer to make this backwards-compatible, so that if the jboss directory exists, it would forward logs to jboss dir, otherwise to wildfly dir.
So, something like the below:

```
$template TmplApplication1, "/whatever/jboss/logs/%fromhost-ip%/sum.log"
$template TmplApplication2, "/whatever/wildfly/logs/%fromhost-ip%/sum.log"
if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then  {
  if /whatever/jboss exists then {
    -?TmplApplication1
    stop
  } else
    -?TmplApplication2
    stop
  }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work. Any idea what the correct syntax would be?

Comment: I dont know of an easy way to do that inside the config. It would be more efficient to test for the directory once outside rsyslogd then set the config appropriately. Eg, you could have 2 conf files and just put the right one in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` for it to be included. Or you can set a variable in the environment to the right dir and get it in in your config with `getenv()` or other mechanisms. Or set a fixed-named symbolic link to the right directory and use that.